# save() not working in ext4yii ExtFormController

Tags: extjs, yii

i tried to insert data using ext4yii form. But the save function in not working. plz look through my code

code of formpanel

```
<ext:Window ClassName="WelcomeWindow" width="500" iconCls="IconApplication"
            bodyPadding="25" bodyStyle="background-color:#fff" layout="fit"
            title="<?php echo Yii::app()->name;?>" closable="false"
            maximizable="false">
    <prop:Items>
  <ext:FormPanel itemId="form1" width="300" title="myform" autoScroll="true">

            <prop:Form>

                <ext:CRUDForm controller="ContactForm" />
  </prop:Form>


       <prop:DockedItems>
        <?php
        include 'ContactView_Editor_Toolbar.php';
        ?>
    </prop:DockedItems>
            <prop:Items>
                <ext:TextField name="Name" fieldLabel="Name"/>

                 <ext:TextField name="address" fieldLabel="Address"/>
            </prop:Items>




    <prop:InstanceBody>
        <script>
            (function(){
                return {
                 StartSaveContact:function()
                    {
                        var me = this;
                        me.mode='new_contact';
                         var msg = me.mode == 'new_contact' ? 'New contact created successfully.' : 'Contact saved successfully.';
                        var form = me.getForm();
                        if(form.isValid()) {
                            var lm = Ext4Yii.newLoadMask(me,'Please wait...',true);
                            form.submit({

                                params:{
                                    mode:me.mode
                                },
                                success:function(form,response) {
                                    lm.hide();
                                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                        title: me.title,
                                        msg: msg,
                                        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                        icon:  Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
                                        fn:function() {

                                        }
                                    });                                                                            
                                },
                                failure:function(form,response) {
                                    lm.hide();
                                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                        title: me.title,
                                        msg: response.result.message,
                                        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                        icon:  Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                        fn:function() {
                                        }
                                    });                                                                                                            
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            })()
        </script>
    </prop:InstanceBody>




        </ext:FormPanel>
  </prop:Items>
</ext:Window>
```

code of contactformcontroller

```
class ContactFormController extends ExtFormController
{

 public function load($request) {

 }
 public function save($data)
 {
      $customer = new Employee();
        /**
         * We can use the setAttributes method on the Customer model
         * since the form names have the same name as the attributes.
         */
        $customer->setAttributes($data);
       if( $customer->save())
            $this->exportData($customer);
        else           
               $this->exportException("Don't know what to do..");   
 }

}
```

the failure function is trigering without showing any message.

Thanks for advance

Comment: I would use ExtJs natively.. pros: once you learn it you can connect it to any back-end not just php, you get to work with the latest version, very nice developer experience with it's ExtJs4 MVC, tons of plugins, you can take advantage of tools like architect ... etc

Comment: And as you can see sencha community is way bigger... plus sencha docs are way better than ext4yii docs

Comment: did you `var_dump($data)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look with firebug , then what kind of error do you get?